# Php generation word list stops at 126MB - Max file size?

Tags: php, file, generator

I wanted to write a simple code that can generate a word list with all possible combination of a set of characters in a specific order, which I did.

Since I didn't want to use my computer power all day generating this list, I had the idea to use my webhotel to generate this file, so I uploaded my code, excecuted it and it worked! Hurray!

The file size kept rising but when I hit around 126MB, it stopped.

What I do is that I assign a letter to a number, and then I simply take one combination at a time and translate the numbers into letters.

Using this method I should not save any giant numbers and that should not be the problem.

**Question:** Is there a max filesize or is something wrong with my code?

Note: The webhotel is Unoeuro.com

My code:

```
<?php
    $uni = fopen("uni.txt", "w");
    $letters = array("ERROR",
                     "a", //1
                     "b", //2
                     "c", //3
                     "d", //4
                     "e", //5
                     "f", //6
                     "g", //7
                     "h", //8
                     "i", //9
                     "j", //10
                     "k", //11
                     "l", //12
                     "m", //13
                     "n", //14
                     "o", //15
                     "p", //16
                     "q", //17
                     "r", //18
                     "s", //19
                     "t", //20
                     "u", //21
                     "v", //22
                     "w", //23
                     "x", //24
                     "y", //25
                     "z"  //26
                    );

    $currentCode = array(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0);
    $dCode = array(26, 26, 26, 9, 9, 26, 26);



while (!empty(array_diff($currentCode, $dCode))){

    $currentCode[7] += 1;

    if ($currentCode[7] === 27){
        $currentCode[7] = 1;

        $currentCode[6] += 1;
    }

    if ($currentCode[6] === 27){
        $currentCode[6] = 1;

        $currentCode[5] += 1;
    }

    if ($currentCode[5] === 27){
        $currentCode[5] = 1;

        $currentCode[4] += 1;
    }

    if ($currentCode[4] === 10){
        $currentCode[4] = 0;

        $currentCode[3] += 1;
    }
    entCode[2] = 1;

        $currentCode[1] += 1;
    }

    if ($currentCode[1] === 27){
        $currentCode[1] = 1;

        $currentCode[0] += 1;
    }

    $code = $letters[$currentCode[0]].$letters[$currentCode[1]].$letters[$currentCode[2]].$currentCode[3].$currentCode[4].$letters[$currentCode[5]].$letters[$currentCode[6]].$letters[$currentCode[7]];
    fwrite($uni, $code."\n");

}

if(empty(array_diff($currentCode, $dCode))){
    $done = fopen(done.txt, "w");
    fwrite($done, "DONE!");

}
    if ($currentCode[3] === 10){
        $currentCode[3] = 0;

        $currentCode[2] += 1;
    }
    if ($currentCode[2] === 27){
        $currentCode[2] = 1;

        $currentCode[1] += 1;
    }

    if ($currentCode[1] === 27){
        $currentCode[1] = 1;

        $currentCode[0] += 1;
    }

    $code = $letters[$currentCode[0]].$letters[$currentCode[1]].$letters[$currentCode[2]].$currentCode[3].$currentCode[4].$letters[$currentCode[5]].$letters[$currentCode[6]].$letters[$currentCode[7]];
    fwrite($uni, $code."\n");

}

if(empty(array_diff($currentCode, $dCode))){
    $done = fopen(done.txt, "w");
    fwrite($done, "DONE!");

}
```

Comment: Anything in the error log? I'd guess memory limit, http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php.

Comment: Either memory limit or max execution time.

Comment: @chris85 As you requested you checked the webserver log any there were 0 errors as i could find

Comment: @CharlotteDunois On unoeuro "admin site" i can check CPU usage and memory, CPU was at max (Which it also was while doing it's job) and memory only at 30%

Comment: And the CPU is still at max (Usualy at the bottom) which could identicate that the webserver is still working, but not doing any real actions?

Comment: These have nothing to do with PHP or PHP's settings.

Comment: The CPU could be at max due to some other process doing something. It's no indicator that the webserver or PHP does something. If you want to see if PHP does something, you need to look into the processes list. But first I'd set the memory_limit and max_execution_time in the php.ini higher (e.g. 512M and 300 (5min)).

Comment: On average before i ran the code it was using 0/25 units (On average) and when i run my code it's at 25/25. My webhotel is currently just being used as my playground aka. no real users

Comment: I changed max memory and execution time and now it is above 2GB so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one wrote an answer i will answer it myself.

As Charlotte Dunois [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814479/php-generation-word-list-stops-at-126mb-max-file-size#comment64997068_38814479) under the question i should try to raise the "memory_limit" and "max_execution_time"

I changed my memory limet to the max capacity i had (Often not recommended) and execution time to an hour (Often not recommended)

And i could succesfully create my wordlist.